# Is there a way to use Meteor's Blaze in a meteor project already created with React integration?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I just want to somehow use the Meteor's accounts-ui package in my meteor x react project.

Comment: https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#blaze-in-react

Comment: but it's a recurring question; also see https://forums.meteor.com/t/accounts-ui-for-react/11642

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, didn't see that in the doc at first. I apologize for the recurring question.